# how to resolve django : ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My application was running fine till few days back, but now all of a sudden i'm seeing this error and not sure what it means, please help.

Error:

```
File "/myproj/myapp/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
from rest_framework import routers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 22, in <module>
from rest_framework import views
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 15, in <module>
from rest_framework.request import Request
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 17, in <module>
from django.http.multipartparser import parse_header
ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_header' from 'django.http.multipartparser' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/multipartparser.py)
```

my line 8 of urls.py is:

```
from rest_framework import routers
```

and i could see the parse_header method in the multipartparser.py file PFA

[multipartparser file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c70Wy.png)

Answer (score 17):

In my opinion, this can be caused by two things:

1. Problem with installing `Django` itself, and in this case I would recommend uninstalling and then reinstalling `Django` using `pip install django`
2. Version mismatch between `Django` and `djangorestframework`, check if the versions of these two packages are compatible.

Please find the documentation link for the release notes attached below:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/

Comment: thanks Ahmad, it was due to django and restframework version mismatch :)

Comment: Version mismatch between Django and djangorestframework, check if the versions of these two packages are compatible. this answer was correct for me. I deleted restframework version number in requirements and reinstalled it again. it worked for me

Comment: Good tip, this should be marked the answer. I got this error after upgrading to Django 4.2. pip install -U djangorestframework fixed it for me (3.13.1 --> 3.14.0 )